# Google Cloud Storage GCS - CORS Wildcard

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

In GCS is it possible to provide Wild card permission for all subdomain under a domain. 
Have referred documentation but it was not provided. 
[GCS CORS Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin)

Answer (score 5):

According to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors wildcards are possible within `Origin` (but not within scheme, so `https://*.stackoverflow.com` works but `http*://*.stackoverflow.com` does not).

Comment: I can't see this mentioned in the linked documentation anymore, but it did work for me.

Answer (score 4):

First you need a cors configuration file that will be applied to your bucket, you can create a wildcard one like this:

```
echo '[{"origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"], "method": ["GET", "HEAD"], "maxAgeSeconds": 3600}]' > cors-config.json
```

Then apply this new config file to your bucket:

```
gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
```

You can check that it has been applied by running the:

```
gsutil cors get gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME
```

command and verifying that the response matched your config file.

(Sources: [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors), [2](https://bitmovin.com/docs/encoding/faqs/how-do-i-set-up-cors-for-my-google-cloud-storage-bucket))

Comment: Mb "wildcard for all subdomain under a domain":
[ { "origin": ["https://*.domain.com"], "responseHeader": ["*"], "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],  "maxAgeSeconds": 3600 } ]

Comment: This will grant permission to all domains, not just all subdomains of a particular website. This may or may not be okay.

Answer (score 0):

CORS subdomain wildcards are not supported in GCS.

Comment: Although I can't see it mentioned anywhere in the documentation, it did work for me, so I'm not sure this is still true, if it was previously.