# Getting CORS issue on wildcard CORS enabled gcs bucket with fetch

Tags: cors, fetch, google-cloud-storage

I have a publicly available file stored in Google Cloud Storage and am having issues when retrieving the resource from a SPA using fetch. Lets say the bucket name is `pub-bucket` and the full resource URL is `https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-bucket/v1/example.mid`. I've enabled CORS using the following JSON config for the bucket

```json
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET"]
    }
]
```

and yet I still receive the same CORS error `Access to fetch at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-bucket/v1/example.mid' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I'm unsure if something is misconfigured as previously I was using DO Spaces with the same CORS config and never saw this issue. I've also tried expanding my CORS config with more options as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57244677/10266342) answer but nothing changed.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out this issue is due to Google not clearly defining which endpoints can be accessed using CORS. This URI version of the resource `https://storage.googleapis.com/[YOUR-BUCKET]/[OBJECT-PATH]` does **not** allow CORS access while `https://[YOUR-BUCKET].storage.googleapis.com/[OBJECT-PATH]` does.

Comment: Hi there Garrett. I am able to make CORS requests with those both xml endpoints. As a matter of fact I have been able to test successfully the behavior from [1]. Perhaps you were affected by the `Max-Age` default value of 1 hour[2]. Have you tried using again the endpoint `https://storage.googleapis.com/[YOUR-BUCKET]/[OBJECT-PATH]`?.

Comment: [1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#server-side-support
[2] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#cors-elements

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and Garrett's solution fixed it! I ran `gsutil cors set <( echo '[{ "origin": ["*"], "method": ["GET"] }]' ) gs://MY-BUCKET`
but continued to get the stupid CORS error for `https://storage.googleapis.com/[MY-BUCKET]/[OBJECT-PATH]`. Changing over to `https://[MY-BUCKET].storage.googleapis.com/[OBJECT-PATH]` fixed it.